# My c# derived class can inherit the base class properties and functions, but throws an exception

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I have created in my 'main' method an object 'spot' of my base class animal were are 4 properties, a 'Animal' class constructor and a function 'SaySomething'. My object 'spot' passes his parameters to the class constructor 'Animal' for initialization. Furthermore, I have created a derived class 'Dog' which is inheriting the base class 'Animal' properties and the method, and I have created an object 'grover' in my 'main' method, and when I try to access with my 'grover' object the method 'SaySomething' which was inherited, my program throws an exception: 'ConsoleApplication1.Animal' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments, when I try to run the program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Animal
    {
        public double height { get; set; }
        public double weight { get; set; }
        public string sound { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public Animal(double height, double weight, string name, string sound)
        {
            this.height = height;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.name = name;
            this.sound = sound;
        }
        public void SaySomething()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} inches tall, weighs {2} lbs and likes to say {3}", name, height, weight, sound);
        }

    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal spot = new Animal(16,10,"spot","woof");
            Dog grover = new Dog();
            grover.SaySomething();
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that I need to delete my class constructor and spot object parameters and arguments that the program could run. But what is wrong with this code? why my program can't run? And need I choose a different initialization way or it is possible to improve this code for working?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. Animal does not have a parameterless constructor, so the Dog class must call that constructor from it's own constructor.

Comment: @Silvermind it doesn't compile.  The OP is incorrectly identifying that as an "exception".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't provide any constructor for `Dog`, it automatically creates an "empty" constructor, that also tries to call the `Animal` "empty" constructor. You need to implement a constructor for `Dog`, or an empty constructor for `Animal`.

Comment: All you need to do is add either of the following to the appropriate class:
public Dog(){}
public Animal(){}

Comment: Assuming you want to allow both `Dog` and `Animal` to be constructed without parameters...

Comment: True. (Actually, I thought I had an 'or' in between them.) ;)

Comment: But how should the code look like if I want that the `Dog` would contain the `Animal` properties which are initialized in the constructor? I don't want to rewrite the same properties for `Dog` which are initialized in the Animal constructor.

Comment: It's already answered, look at the duplicate.

Comment: Oh, I see now.. Thank you!